# using FXG with FlashBuilder 4.5 on ActionScript Mobile project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, fxg

I've been successfully building AS3 projects that import FXG graphics using FlashBuilder 4 for web.

I'm now upgrading to FlashBuilder4.5 so I can build mobile apps but I'm getting an error when I try and using FXGs

The error is

The definition of base class SpriteVisualElement was not found. [Generated code (use -keep to save): Path: data\gold-interface.as, Line: 6, Column: 27]

The line and column number don't seem to relate to anything I can understand...

Can anyone point me in the correct direction to solving this please?

thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

This is an error in generated code. If you go to your project properties, and go to Flex compiler, you can add the

```
-keep
```

option to the compilation. This will retain the generated code in the "generated" subfolder of your src folder. From there you can inspect the gold-interface.as file. That's the best I can offer with the information you've given.

There's the potential this is a bug in the Flex compiler (MXML compiler) introduced in 4.5, or an incompatability with FXG (disclaimer: I've never used FXG)